# AWS SQS - setup for horizontal scaling

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-sqs, horizontal-scaling

I am using AWS SQS so two of my applications (lets call them app 1 and app 2) can interact with one another. So far, app 1 was sending a message to queue, while app 2 was listening and processing the message sent from app 1. The flow is that client (reactJS application) sends http request to app 1, app 1 forwards the message to app 2 using AWS SQS, and then app 2 through the websockets broadcast certain message to all other users/clients (the important thing here is that all websocket connections are in app 2)

But, in past period I needed to implement horizontal scaling of app 2 (I am running exactly 2 instances of app 2) and now websocket connections are separated, some websocket connections are on instance 1 of app 2 and some websocket connections are on instance 2 of app 2. So lately I am facing the challenge where app 1 sends the message to queue and then just one of the instances of app 2 reads the message.

So my question would be is there a possibility that both of instances of app 2 reads the SQS message or there is some other way to handle this situation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, a [fan-out](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/send-fanout-event-notifications/) (more info also [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fan-out-to-different-sqs-queues-using-sns-message-filtering-84cd23ed9d07)) architecture would solve your issue. In the architecture, your app 1 would be sending message to SNS topic instead of SQS queue. Then you would subscribe **two SQS queues** to the topic, so that each instance has its own topic. This way, the message would be broadcast two the two instances of app 2.

If you can't change the initial SQS into SNS, you would need to **re-broadcast** the messages from the SQS into the SNS, for example, using a lambda function.

The architecture is also very **scalable**, since when you add third instance, you just add third SQS queue.